# Prolog - unifying two lists with/without variables

Tags: list, variables, prolog, unification

This Prolog code returns:

```
?- [a,b,c,d]  =  [a|[b,c,d]].
```

true

and this one

```
?- [X,Y] = [a|[b,c,d]].
```

returns false.

I am not totally grasping why `[X, Y]` is false. Trace is not helpful here. I would expect the following assignment to hold

```
X = a
Y = [b,c,d]
```

and the statement be true.

What does `|` do besides splitting on head and tail?

Comment: `[X,Y]` is a list of 2 elements. `[a|[b,c,d]]` is a list of 4 elements, being equivalent to `[a,b,c,d]`. So these two terms cannot be unified, and thus the false result. Perhaps you meant to write `[X|Y] = [a|[b,c,d]]`? A `,` is a list element separator. The `|` indicates a head/tail relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list in Prolog is implemented as a linked list of functors. If you write a list like `[a, b, c, d]`. it looks in reality like:

```
+-------+
| (|)/2 |
+---+---+   +-------+
| o | o---->| (|)/2 |
+-|-+---+   +---+---+   +-------+
  v         | o | o---->| (|)/2 |
  a         +-|-+---+   +---+---+   +-------+
              v         | o | o---->| (|)/2 |
              b         +-|-+---+   +---+---+   
                          v         | o | o----> []
                          c         +-|-+---+
                                      v
                                      d
```

or in Prolog notation `[a | [b | c | [d | [] ] ] ]`. The comma-separated list is *syntactical sugar*: if you write `[a, b, c, d]`, the Prolog interpreter converts it to a representation as above.

Since `[b, c, d]` is equal to:

```
[ b | [ c | [ d | [] ] ] ]
```

and thus `[ a | [b, c, d] ]` is thus equal to

```
[a | [b | c | [d | [] ] ] ]
```

But the list `[X, Y]` is just equal to

```
[X, Y] == [ X | [ Y | [] ] ]
```

or in a structural way:

```
+-------+
| (|)/2 |
+---+---+   +-------+
| o | o---->| (|)/2 |
+-|-+---+   +---+---+
  v         | o | o----> []
  X         +-|-+---+
              v
              Y
```

If we then match it with `[a | [b | c | [d | [] ] ] ]` this means the "outer" shell can be matched, so `X = a`, but then `Y = b`, and `[] = [ c | [ d | [] ] ]`. The last part does not match, and thus it returns `false`. The `X` and `Y` are thus not the problem. The problem is that `[]` is a constant, and it does not match with the functor that represents `[ c | [d] ]`.

If we would for example unify `[ X | Y ] == [a, b, c, d]` we get:

```
?- [ X | Y ] = [a, b, c, d].
X = a,
Y = [b, c, d].
```

So to conclude, one can say that `|` itself "does" nothing. It is a functor, just like `f(1, 2)`. In Lisp they used [`cons` [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) for this, and `nil` for the empty list. So `[1, 4, 2, 5]` looks in Lisp like `cons 1 (cons 4 (cons 2 (cons 5 nil)))`, or in Prolog it would look like `cons(1, cons(4, cons(2, cons(5, nil))))`. It is only a bit cumbersome to write. In fact the comma separated notation is more the "magic" part. Prolog just performs unification for lists, just like it does for other functors and constants.

Comment: Thank you, Let us consider the simplest case of only two elements. Can we strip syntactic sugar everywhere and define: `a|b = f(a,b)` and `[a,b] = f(a,b)`. What is definition of `[]` and `|`? It seems like we have `[]` defined in terms of `|` and `|` is only defined with respect to `[]`. A bit circular...

Comment: @user1700890: no `[a, b] = f(a, f(b, nil))`, with `nil` the "empty list" (the end of the list). Note that Prolog sees `[X|Y]` thus as "standard" way to represent such `f(X, Y)`. the `[` and `]` are part of the syntax. Note that `f/2` takes a head, and a tail, for `[a,b]` then `a` is the head, but `b` is *not* the tail, `b` is the "next element", and thus we need a list as tail: `[b]`, or with our functor `f(b, nil)`.

Comment: You can see `[X|Y]` as a syntax to write `f(X, Y)`, but `[X, Y]` is syntactical sugar *on top* of that concept, in the sense that this does not result in *one* functor, but in a structure of functors.

Comment: Thank you again. I guess I am clear now. Let us take shorter example: `[X,Y] = [a|[b,c]]`, then `[X,Y]=f(X, f(Y,nil))` and `[a|[b,c]]= f(a,f(b,f(c,nil)))`. So the statement is false, because `f(c, nil)` and `nil` do not unify.

Comment: @user1700890: exactly: in Prolog a constant is only considered equal with itself (through unification a variable can of course get that constant as value), and a functor unifies with the same functor (same name and same arith) and all the arguments are the same. Now `nil` and `f(c, nil)` clearly are not equal since `nil` is a constant, and `f` is a functor with two parameters.

Comment: @user1700890 `nil` is just an *atom*, as are terms like `joe` or `foo`. `nil` has no more special meaning in Prolog than any other atom. As far as lists go, in Prolog the list `[H | T]` is actually syntactic sugar for `'.'(H, T)`, which is the canonical form of a list in Prolog. `[X,Y] = f(X, f(Y,nil))` fails because `f` and `'.'` are not the same functor. If you used `'.'` instead of `F`, then it would still fail because `'.'(X, '.'(X,nil))` could be written `[X, Y | nil]`. The atom `nil` is *not* the empty list. The empty list is represented by the special term `[]`.